# Whats wrong with this PHP IF statement?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I've got a PHP IF statement to save different SQL results in a PHP variable ($sql) based on the IF conditions, but it keeps returning SQL results based on just one condition (the first one), regardless of what the user enters in the POST'd values.

All of the SQL statements work as expected when entered into phpMyAdmin individually (whilst changing the $row3 and $row4 to actual values that exist), just not with the PHP IF statement.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here, and if possible advise what I need to do differently? I know I'm no PHP / MySQL expert, but I'm stumped :(

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$row3 = $_POST['groups'];
$row4 = $_POST['othercode-all'];

IF ($row3='-all-' && ($row4='-all-')) 
{
$sql ="SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'";
}


ELSEif ($row3!='-all-' && ($row4='-all-')) 
{
$sql ="SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '$row3'";
}


ELSEIF ($row4 != '-all-' && ($row3 = '-all-'))
{
$sql ="SELECT
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND othercode = '$row4'";
}

ELSE
{
$sql ="SELECT   
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '$row3' AND othercode = '$row4'";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it

```
if ($row3 == '-all-' && $row4 == '-all-') {
     // Do the stuff
} elseif ($row3 != '-all-' && $row4 == '-all-') {
     // Do another
}
```

You are not checking you are assigning.

1)`=` will assign the right side values to left.In your case it will always `true` bec you are assigning the string.

2)But `==` will only checks both left and right side values/variables.

3)And `===` will also check for the data type of both of them,for either int,float or string..etc

And I can see that in each condition all query is same but changing little at `where` condition.So better you take query which is common and in the condition attach the where condition.It will readable and may reliable too.

Comment: Same story goes for the ELSEIF.

Comment: Your a genius! Well, compared to me you are lol. Thank you so much!

At the moment I'm just glad to get this working for now, but I will try and follow through with your last paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

As you used a single equals sign,  the first statement you wrote will always return true. There is also no need for the internal brackets after the && operator.

```
IF ($row3='-all-' && ($row4='-all-')) {}
```

Should be:

```
if ($row3 == '-all-' && $row4 == '-all-') {}
```

If I were to write

```
if ($var = 'test') {}
```

It will always evaluate to true as the value of $var is successfully set and returned. The only situation I can think of where this would not return true, is if you were passing a variable as the value, and it either did not exist or evaluated to false.

In your case you want the comparison operator '==', as you are not testing to see if a value can set, but rather that it is a specific value.

As you are also testing for the same value each time it also makes sense to declare that elsewhere:

```
$str = '-all-';
if ($row3 == $str && $row4 == $str) { //logic }
```

The === operator also checks type, and would not be useful in this case.
If you are comparing a var to see if it validates to a TRUE boolean then it is useful as a non-false/null/empty value evaluates as TRUE, even though it is not a TRUE boolean:

```
$t1 = 'FALSE';
$t2 = FALSE;

if ($t1 === FALSE)
//evaluates as false as t2 is a string not a boolean
if ($t2 === FALSE)
//evaluates as true
```

Finally, there is also no need for the brackets as you are not grouping conditions together.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is also worth you checking that the user actually posted information in the $_POST fields, as in it's current state the whole script will not execute if one of the fields is left blank.

You can use !is_empty($row3) to make sure you don't send empty values to the mysql query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. What is POST'd is from a html select, so something will always be posted, I think all that can go wrong there is that they may choose the wrong option.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try:

```
$row3 = ($_POST['groups']=='-all-') ? '%' : $_POST['groups'];
$row4 = ($_POST['othercode-all']=='-all-') ? '%' : $_POST['othercode-all'];

$sql ="SELECT   
  email,
  accountgroup, othercode
FROM
  (SELECT
        email AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email2 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        email3 AS email,
        accountgroup, othercode
   FROM
        accounts) account
WHERE
  email LIKE '%@%'
  AND accountgroup = '$row3' AND othercode = '$row4'";
```

This way the code is simpler. You always use the where clause, but searching anything when its value is -all-.

Comment: That does look much neater, thank you. I did try it but it didn't seem to work for me. When -all- is posted for both options it only returns a few rows, as opposed to a couple of hundred as it should do. The rows it returns are the accounts that have no accountgroup or othercode assigned.